# Swift 3 - Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'valueForKey'

Tags: swift3

Hi I have updated to swift 3 and am getting the error:

> Value of type 'Any?' has no member 'valueForKey'

for the following lines of code:

```
let userName : NSString? = result.valueForKey("name") as? NSString
let facebookID : NSString? = result.valueForKey("id") as? NSString
let firstName : NSString? = result.valueForKey("first_name") as? NSString
let lastName : NSString? = result.valueForKey("last_name") as? NSString
let email : NSString? = result.valueForKey("email") as? NSString
```

What is the explanation for theses errors and how would I go about fixing it?

Many thanks!

EDIT:

Full Code:

```html
  if((FBSDKAccessToken.current()) != nil){
            FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection, result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    
                    
                    let userName : NSString? = result.valueForKey("name") as? NSString
                    let facebookID : NSString? = result.valueForKey("id") as? NSString
                    let firstName : NSString? = result.valueForKey("first_name") as? NSString
                    let lastName : NSString? = result.valueForKey("last_name") as? NSString
                    let email : NSString? = result.valueForKey("email") as? NSString
```

ANSWER:

```html
  FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection,  result, error) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    
                    let data:[String:AnyObject] = result as! [String : AnyObject]
                    
                    
                    let userName : NSString? = data["name"]! as? NSString
                    let facebookID : NSString? = data["id"]! as? NSString
                    let firstName : NSString? = data["first_name"]! as? NSString
                    let lastName : NSString? = data["last_name"]! as? NSString
                    let email : NSString? = data["email"]! as? NSString
```

Comment: Can you please show us, how you define `result` and what type it is?

Comment: You might cast `result` to something more meaningful than the unspecified `Any`

Comment: `Since id now imports as Any rather than AnyObject, you may see errors where you were previously performing dynamic lookup on AnyObject.` in [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Introduction.html) _ctrl+f -> any_

Comment: Thanks! Edited post with answer!

Answer (score 3):

Though you find an answer but its better to use pure swift approach rather than using `NSString` and better not to force unwrap optionals

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, first_name, last_name, email"]).start(completionHandler: { (connection,  result, error) -> Void in
            if (error == nil){
                  guard let data = result as? [String:Any] else { return }

                  let fbid = data["id"] 
                  let username = data["name"]  
                  let firstName = data["first_name"]
```